# How do I run jar files online

Tags: java

i have created a sophisticated software using java,but most people these day use internet applications,if i create a web based application using html/css/javascript it will take me months or years,i wanted to know if its possible to run my jar application online?

is it possible to run a jar file on mobile (android,ios,blackberry os),Xamarin converts c# application is it possible to convert jar files?

Comment: Are you looking for Java Applets? Note you need to get it signed by a CA due to new Java security requirements.

Comment: If you go the way of Java applets, you'll probably encounter a slew of users who have Java disabled in their browser because of a history of severe insecurities with applets.